# Django deployment with fabric

Tags: django, fabric

I am trying to build a django-based web console for deploying my sites with fabric, in which there are dropdowns for different hosts(prod/stage) and different branches from git and able to select and submit to execute the fabric command accordingly.

The problem is I want to have a html textarea in this console to be able to show the output of fabric commands.

E.g. [myhostname] run: git pull origin master (in a textarea from ajax request)

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a simple [example](https://gist.github.com/bortzmeyer/1284249) I've found. So you can similarly call your fab commands and catch ouput through PIPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer, this can be done by:

```
local('git pull capture=True')
```